# How to make a batch file copy itself in all folders and subfolders

Tags: batch-file

I want to make a batch file copy itself in all folders and subfolders.
For example : i have a folder on my desktop called "root". inside that folder i have 3 folders : 'a','b' and 'c'. Inside 'a' there are yet other folders a1, and a2.

Now i want to make a batch file to copy itself in every folder available.

I tried using for loop like this:

`for /d %%a in (*.*) do copy file.txt "%%a"`

but it doesn't copy to all folders

Please help
thnx

Answer (score 1):

```
for /d /r %%# in (*) do copy /y "%~f0" "%%#"
```

Answer (score 1):

`for /R %%a in (%~nx0) do copy /y "%~nx0" "%%a"`

Comment: "%~nx0" - better use "%~f0" as the working directory could change.